# Как в react задать checkbox?

Tags: reactjs

Суть вопроса такова. Мы берем массив, перебираем его и создаем инпуты ckeckbox в render() react

Как составить правильно массив, и как прописать в Render, что какие то инпуты с активным ckeckbox а какие то нет?
Ну то есть как написать
checkbox={item.checkbox} что должно быть прописано в массиве что бы checkbox был неактивен?

```js
 
 lis = this.state.NotesArr.map( (item, index) => {
                return (
                <input
                key={index}
                type="checkbox"
                style={this.state.divbody}
                checkbox= 
                >   
                </input>)
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Дайте еще ваш `state`.

Comment: state нет еще. И массива нет. Я хочу понять как вообще в массиве записывать это

Answer (score 5):

Реакт отрендерит только то и таким образом, каким вы его запрограммируете. Поэтому в массиве может быть что угодно, к примеру

https://codesandbox.io/s/p7n3511yz0

```
const data = [
  { title: 'test1', active: false },
  { title: 'test2', active: true },
  { title: 'test3', active: false },
  { title: 'test4', active: true },
  { title: 'test5', active: false },
  { title: 'test6', active: true },
];


const Checkbox = ({ label, selected }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked={selected} />
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    {data.map(item => <Checkbox selected={item.active} label={item.title} />)}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Ну так оно заблокировало chekbox. Как теперь пользователю отключить чекбокс или включить

Comment: Это тот момент, когда вам придётся исследовать проблему самому основываясь на открытых источниках. "Оно заблокировало checkbox" это как раз то, как в реакте в 99% случаев работают формы. Ключевые слова "react onchange event handling"